Switch Windows of Application across Workspaces
I have GNOME 46 on Ubuntu 24.04 configured to switch windows using Alt+Tab

This way I can switch all Windows of all applications but this only works one the current workspace but not across all workspaces.
Hitting Alt+Tab only shows the applications running on the current workspace.

This info may help: https://superuser.com/a/860001/981581

Thanks, gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false did the trick!

Ahh, that would be better.  I was going to say 'show on all workspaces` but you'd have to set every app.
